# SSL fixed content , why is not returning site_url() , in https scheme

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, mixed-content

In my WordPress site, I'm using another WordPress in sub-folder like: `https://www.mywpexample.com/wp-newsite`

I have done SSL for my Site, but suddenly showing there console Mixed content https not loading errors , and not loading any assets (*css/js/actions*) in site `https://www.mywpexample.com/wp-newsite`.

I have tried to `echo site_url()` its return's `http://www.mywpexample.com/wp-newsite` but in the database and wordpress general setting I have already:

> WordPress Address (URL) -> `https://www.mywpexample.com/wp-newsite`
>
> Site Address (URL)  -> `https://www.mywpexample.com/wp-newsite`

And on the wp-config file:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.mywpexample.com/wp-newsite' );
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.mywpexample.com/wp-newsite' );
define('ABSOLUTE_URL', 'www.mywpexample.com/wp-newsite');
```

If trying to add SSL options like in wp-config:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL', true)
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true)
```

After Site Breaking and browser showing errors for `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.
For now, I have got this solution for front-end replace all http --> to https.. in root `index.php`

```
<?php
ob_start();
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

//and these lines also 
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$output = str_replace(array("https://", "http://"), "//", $output);
echo str_replace('http:\/\/', "\/\/", $output);
```

But Need a better solution which , work for all environments (*wp-admin, wp-login and front-end*).

Comment: Have you replace `"http://www.mywpexample.com"` by `"https://www.mywpexample.com"` on all tables ?

Comment: @bazaim I'm avoiding dump and restore process for entire database , and also I'm not sure this will work.. But I thing, I have updated  `siteurl` and `home` meta key from `wp_options` table , then it should work for theme and plugin files.

Comment: I've no idea of the source of your problem. 
Maybe you should try to replace all url with this tools : https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guy's If you going this same issue . "Mixed content blocking"

Please use the following [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/)

if using ngnix server , that's change in plugin setting according your server recommendations .[image]